# How to show updated time for DST countries?

Tags: php, datetime, phpmailer, dst

I am showing time for different time-zones and the problem is that my server is running PHP v5.3.25 whereas on my local computer I have v5.5.9

When I set a specific time-zone and display its time, my local computer shows it just fine but the server does not add hours during DST.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

I have created a workaround for it:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$is_dst = date('I');
if($is_dst) {
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+1 hours', strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))));
} else {
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
echo $date;
```

This workaround is fine for UK but I want a dynamic and a valid solution to display time. Moreover, when I send email using PHPMailer, it shows wrong timestamp on the receiving end because of this daylight saving issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the server time was not synchronized with the UTC time. I opened a ticket with my hosting provider and they started NTP service for me. So the issue was not with the PHP but the NTP service being stopped. Now my server time is synchronized and the daylight saving is also being followed.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a reliable way to handle DST since some places don't use full hours, or don't have it at all. [The DateTime extension](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) handles all that for you, and it's been there since PHP 5.2, so you should be able to do this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');
$date = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('Europe/Amsterdam'));
```

Generally you should always use UTC for internal timestamps, otherwise it's really easy to get very confused. Convert to the user's time zone whenever you need to display something to them - though of course that means you need to know the user's time zone, and generally you need to get that from JS since it's not included in `$_SERVER`, though you could infer it from geoip data, or ask the user to specify a zone explicitly in your app's prefs.